# Creating New Document Libraries (not documents) from existing saved Document Library Template SP365

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, template, default

We manage numerous clients in their own respective Document Libraries. However, each of these Libraries needs to have the same general "settings." Same columns, same view options, same row formatting, etc.

You can create a template from a Document Library via `Library Settings -> Save document library as template`. So, I have done this. BUT...

After doing all of this, I am not able to find any way to create a new Document Library based on that template? Can someone fill in what I am missing here?

Ideally I need this to be a default template for when people create new libraries.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If you have further questions, please feel free to reply.

Comment: Yes. Issue was there was no interface feedback indicating it was saved as an app (completely unintuitive) and then furthermore, hidden in Modern view (must switch to Classic View).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to site contents -> add an app -> find the existing library template.

Comment: Thank you Emily - I see no templates listed there? My template was saved to the "List Template Gallery." When I follow your instructions, I arrive at "Apps you can add" screen and the template is not listed, even when searched...

Comment: On a whim I decided to select "View in Classic Experience." Then, I searched for it and boom - it appeared. So weird though - Modern vs Classic actually functions differently? Seems like a bug??

Comment: If you will append to your answer: "If you cannot find the template in Modern view, switch to "View in classic appearance" and then search for the template there." I will mark yours as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it should go to classic experience to add library template.