# How to create template for new document library on Teams web

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, site-column, team-sites, template

I need to create several document libraries with the same columns and formatting under my Teams web.

I have looked into e. g. this question:

[Creating New Document Libraries (not documents) from existing saved Document Library Template SP365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300156/creating-new-document-libraries-not-documents-from-existing-saved-document-lib)

But I do not see anywhare any option **to save my existing document library as a template**.
Does it mean it is not supported in the tenant? When I click advanced library properties it takes me to a classic looking settings page with no such option.

Comment: Save as template option is not available in SharePoint online modern experience sites by default. You can check PnP Provisioning engine or custom site templates which creates document library using available actions/verbs.

Comment: What about Microsoft Graph API...?